# Algebra - How can I graph this function and work with exponential function with base $a$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm having a hard time to go through this exercise, anyone willing to help me before I go crazy?

Thank you so much in advance!

Graph the function $f(x) = 5(0.5)^{-x}$ and its reflection about the line $y = x$ on the same axis, and give the $x$-intercept of the reflection.  Prove that $a^x = e^{x\ln a}$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE.  Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: Did you manage to graph the function?

Answer (score 2):

The graph $f(x)=5(0.5)^{−x}$ is a reflection of the graph $g(x)=5(0.5)^x$ in the $y$-axis.

To find the reflection of $f(x)$ in the line $y=x$, ie its inverse, we make $x$ the subject:

$$y=5(0.5)^{−x}\implies 0.5^{-x}=\frac{y}{5}\implies 2^x=\frac{y}{5}\implies x =\log_2 \frac{y}{5}$$
So, where $h(x)$ is the inverse function:
$$h(x)=\log_2 \frac{x}{5}$$
Now, for the last part: Using log and exponential laws:
$$a^x=e^{\ln{a^x}}=e^{x\ln a}$$
as required.